# Uninstall other apps from my application, handling user input

Tags: java, android

I used the code, it works fine. In the uninstall process it asks the user to choose an uninstaller option (packageinstaller and my app). How to skip this?
or how detect which button clicked by user? (ok or cancel)

```
 Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.android.myapp");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);

private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  
{

 @Override  
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)  
    {  
        //here dell app with startActivity(uninstallIntent);
     BlackListActivity.getInstance().dellApp(params[0]);
     return "done";
    }   

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String sss) {
    //when call update list,program has stoped, how detect uninstall process done
     BlackListActivity.getInstance().updatedData();
    // super.onPostExecute(null);
    
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to manage the user's apps unless you have what's called the firmware key.  Essentially, that would give your app special rights that a standard app won't have.  Otherwise, there will always be some user interaction with install/uninstall.

If you didn't build and deploy the OS, you won't get the firmware key.  You'd need to contact the manufacturer and have them sign your app for you, and unless you're ordering many thousands of devices from them, they won't do that (and usually not then either).

I would guess you'll get virtually no info from whatever app is opened to actually do the uninstall.  I could be wrong, but I highly doubt it.

You *could* try to query the current apps in the system and find the package name of whatever's on top.  That'll at least give you info on what the user opened to remove the app, but you'll need to do something really fast, assuming the user is in the process of uninstalling your app (unless, of course, you have a separate app installed doing the watching).

Comment: i have list of installed program in my device and i want the user select applications and when clicked uninstall button then applications uninstall and update list.

Comment: application for example: *360 antivirus* (uninstall tab)

Comment: Yeah, I've used a few of these myself.  They all need to open another screen to actually uninstall.  Unless you work for Samsung (or htc, asus, etc), you can't do that.

Comment: My problem is: when the uninstall page open and After running the uninstall manager. I'll update the list of program,but my program is stoped.my code:
unistallapps("example");
updatelist();

Comment: You'd need to post code.  I'd just refresh your list every time you hit onResume.